# Is there anyway to remove default focus highlighting on a composable in a lazyrow?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-tv, android-jetpack-compose-tv

When I move focus to any of the items in a lazy row (Box composable), android by default darkens the background of that element to show that it being focussed. I don't need this as I am adding my own focus effects.

Is there some way to remove this?

The following is the implementation of the lazy row I have:

```
LazyRow(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .align(Alignment.BottomStart)){
                 items(dataList){item -> SceneCard(data)}
```

Fun SceneCard:

```
Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter,modifier = Modifier
    .onFocusChanged { isFocused = it.hasFocus }
    .clickable(enabled = true) {}
    .animateContentSize(
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 300)
    )
    .fillMaxHeight()
){//some content}
```

Comment: Can you add to your question how did you implement the `LazyRow` method?

Comment: @G.Ciardini you can refer to the code snippet above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution to this, the trick was in the `.clickable` modifier function:

Instead of just using

```
Modifier.clickable(enabled = true) {}
```

I fixed it by using

```
Modifier.clickable(
    interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource(),
    indication = null,
    onClick = {})
```